# Reply with the embedded message on C++ Discord API Bot Library (DPP)

Tags: c++, d++

The problem is that he doesn't answer me with an embed message, I would like a little help if possible (btw, I'm new here)

I expected it to work, I tried with gpt chat to solve the problem with `event.reply(dpp::interaction_response_type::EMBED, embed);` or `event.reply(embed);` still the same error or different.

This is a code

```
#include <dpp/dpp.h>

const std::string BOT_TOKEN = "--------";

int main() {
    dpp::cluster bot(BOT_TOKEN);

    bot.on_log(dpp::utility::cout_logger());

    bot.on_slashcommand([](const dpp::slashcommand_t& event) {
        if (event.command.get_command_name() == "ping") {
            event.reply("Pong!");
        }
        // Check if the command name is "review"
        else if (event.command.get_command_name() == "review") {
            // Respond with the review message
            event.reply("Ai uitat să lași un review? Urât din partea ta, apasa repede la http://distopia.mywebcommunity.org/review.php și postează un review ;)");
        }
        // Check if the command name is "website"
        else if (event.command.get_command_name() == "website") {
            // Respond with the website message
            event.reply("Vrei să inviți un prieten, uite un mic link http://distopia.mywebcommunity.org/ pentru a face o mică prezentare la server:))");
        }
        // Check if the command name is "version"
        else if (event.command.get_command_name() == "version") {
            // Create an embedded message
            dpp::embed embed;
            embed.set_title("Bot and API Distopia Versions");
            embed.set_description("Iată versiunile actuale ale botului și API Distopia:");
            embed.set_color(0x3498db); // BULLSHIT COLOR

            // Add fields to the embedded message
            embed.add_field("Bot Version", "3.0", true); // Inline field
            embed.add_field("API Distopia Version", "Working.. progress..", true); // Inline field
            embed.add_field("Security pach", "Working...", false); // Non-inline field

            // Reply with the embedded message
            event.reply();
        }
    });

    bot.on_ready([&bot](const dpp::ready_t& event) {
        if (dpp::run_once<struct register_bot_commands>()) {
            bot.global_command_create(dpp::slashcommand("ping", "Ping pong!", bot.me.id));
            bot.global_command_create(dpp::slashcommand("review", "Review.", bot.me.id));
            bot.global_command_create(dpp::slashcommand("website", "Website", bot.me.id));
            bot.global_command_create(dpp::slashcommand("version", "Bot Version", bot.me.id));
        }
    });

    bot.start(dpp::st_wait);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [no-parameter overload](https://dpp.dev/structdpp_1_1interaction__create__t.html#a34f374b358f8d2d49fa93bfe5a2c0493) (or, rather, single-parameter overload with default argument) you used in `event.reply()`, per documentation, only acknowledges interaction and doesn't send any meaningful message (and obviously there's no way it could know about local variable `embed` when it isn't passed in any way). Other two options you listed shouldn't even compile (that's what you probably meant by 'different' error).

Instead, you should embed the `embed` (no pun intended) into `dpp::message` and use the [appropriate `dpp::slashcommand_t::reply` overload](https://dpp.dev/structdpp_1_1interaction__create__t.html#aebdd5a0cd0258a372dc1b55aa594a44a):

```
// ...
// Reply with the message containing embed to appropriate channel
dpp::message message(event.command.channel_id, embed);
event.reply(message);
```